# Datatables "Requested unknown parameter 'UserNo' for row 0, column 0". (using asp.net mvc core)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I need your help to solve this error...

My JSON data from controller to view looks like this :

```
{"data":[{"userNo":2,"useState":0,"regDate":"2019-01-01","updDate":null}]}
```

And My Code :

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetEmployeeList()
    {
        List<User> data  = new List<User>();

            User objUser = new User(); // In User Model, I have UserNo/UseState/RegDate/UpdDate Column.

            objUser.UserNo   = 2;
            objUser.UseState = 0;
            objUser.RegDate  = "2019-01-01";
            //objUser.UpdDate = ""; //I don't need UpdDate at this moment, so it's null now.

            data.Add(objUser);
        return Json(new {data});
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#tblList').dataTable({
            ajax: {
                "url": '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeList", "Point")',
                "type": "POST",
            },
            columns: [
                { data: "UserNo" },
                { data: "UseState" },
                { data: "RegDate" },
                { data: "UpdDate" }
            ],
            ordering: false,
            searching: false,
            serverSide: false
        });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table" id="tblList">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>UserNo</th>
                <th>UseState</th>
                <th>RegDate</th>
                <th>UpdDate</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

I tried 'tbody' tag in HTML, "dataSrc":"" in Javascript But Nothing worked.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small overlook! Its the upperCase "U" in "UserNo" why you are getting the error, and you would get same error for other keys too. Your JSON has all key names beginning with lower case letter. Make sure you reference Datatables column data in exactly the same way as they appear in JSON.

```
columns: [
            { data: "userNo" },
            { data: "useState" },
            { data: "regDate" },
            { data: "updDate" }
        ],
```

Comment: omg i've never thought about those. I fixed it and thanks a lot!!